# Is it normal to use ‘the second’ without a preposition in expressing ‘as soon as” or ‘no later than’?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

I saw the following sentence in Time magazine’s (December 3) article titled “Betraying physical book: A book lover’s e-dilemma:

> “When electronic books first came out, I embraced them wholeheartedly.
>   In fact, I was one of the first to buy Amazon’s Kindle electronic book
>   reader **the second** it was available.”

Is “the second” used adverbially? What is the function of ‘the second’ as a part of speech in this instance? Is it common to drop a preposition (in or at) before ‘the second (minute, moment, or instant)’ in expressing simultaneity?

Comment: Indeed it _is_ common to drop the preposition in this context. At least one dictionary describes this usage as [idiomatic](http://books.google.com/books?id=pqlRO2jdI2gC&pg=PA603&dq=%22The+minute+I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WerSUIaXIsmq2gWC5IDYBw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBDgo#v=onepage&q=%22The%20minute%20I%22&f=false).

Comment: Any exception to general usage in a particular case, like dropping a normal marker, marks the construction as at least venially idiomatic. For _second_, one can substitute any other time unit, though the intent varies; _second_ is indeed hyperbolic; _minute_ is less so. _Hour_ or _day_, on the other hand, are out of place in this sentence, but they can also appear with a preposition in appropriate sentences _The day he got here he told me about it._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using "the second it was available" is hyperbole. The normal way of expressing that is "*as soon as* it was (made) available". You can replace "second" with "instant" or "minute" to maintain the hyperbole. "The second" looks like an adverbial phrase of time, just as "as soon as" is an adverbial phrase of time.

You could change "the second" to "at the very {second/moment/instant/minute} it appeared" if you wanted to use a prepositional phrase, but it's not necessary.